# Harnack for ball of radius $1/2$ imply Harnack for ball of any radius

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Suppose $u$ is a nonnegatieve (but not identically zero) integrable function defined on $B_2(0)$, ball of radius $2$ and centred at $0$ such that
$$
\sup_{B\frac{1}{2}(0)}\,u\leq C\inf_{B_{\frac{1}{2}(0)}}\,u
$$
for some positive constant $C$.

Then I hope the following fact is also true:
For any ball $B_r(0)$ where $r<2$, one has
$$
\sup_{B_r(0)}\,u\leq D\inf_{B_r(0)}\,u,
$$
for some positive constant $D$ depedning on the ball $B_r(0)$.

I tried to prove in the following way: Since closure of $B_r(0)$ is compact, by compactness, we can cover it by a finite number of balls (say $m$) $B$ each of radius $\frac{1}{2}$ centred at $0$.

Moreover, observe that from the given condition
$$
\sup_{B\frac{1}{2}(0)}\,u\leq C\inf_{B_{\frac{1}{2}(0)}}\,u
$$
for some positive constant $C$, and since $u\geq 0(\neq 0)$, we have $u\geq C_1>0$ in $B_\frac{1}{2}(0)$ and therefore $u\geq C_2$ in $B_r(0)$ for some positive constant $C_2$.

Now since $B_r(0)\subset\overline{B_r(0)}$ and using the above finite number of coverings, we obtain
$$
\sup_{B_r(0)}\,u\leq \sup_{\overline{B_r(0)}}\,u\leq C_{m}\sup_{B_{\frac{1}{2}(0)}}\,u\leq d_{m}\inf_{B_{\frac{1}{2}(0)}}\,u\leq e_{m}\inf_{B_r(0)}\,u,
$$
for some positive constants $c_m, d_m$ and $e_m$, which are finite since the number of covering is finite. In this way $e_m$ depending on $B_r$.

I hope the argument is correct.

Can somebody kindly help me if you think there is some problem in the argument?

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Your inequality involving $D$ is independent of $r$. Is it intentional?

Comment: Well, the union of any amount of balls with radius $1/2$ and center $0$ is always $B_{1/2}(0)$.

Comment: As I can see from the argument, the constant $e_m$ is the constant $D$ in our required inequality. @ Arctic Char

Comment: But I want to know if you think my argument is fine? @ Arctic Char

Comment: I mean this "For any ball $B_r(0)$ where $r<2$, one has
$$
\sup_{B\frac{1}{2}(0)}\,u\leq D\inf_{B_{\frac{1}{2}(0)}}\,u,
$$
for some positive constant $D$ depedning on the ball $B_r(0)$". There's no $r$ in the inequality?

Comment: Thank you very much @ Arctic Char. I have edited the question. Now please inform if the argument is fine according to you.